# Changing one field in a CSV file fails using pipes

Tags: powershell

I need to modify one (1) field in a CSV file. I can do it with separate commands, but the CSV file may be large (GiB+). My understanding is that `Import-Csv` will read the entire file into memory unless it is piped to another process. Is that correct?

Using separate commands on a small file works, but the pipelined command produces no output. What am I missing?

```
PS C:\src\powershell> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1

PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Content .\eximtest.ps1
$infile = ".\eximtest.csv"

"id,name,breed
1,Ruby,cat
2,Ralph,dog
3,Asia,cat" | Out-File $infile

# Non-pipeline approach, reads all of $infile into $csv
$csv = Import-Csv $infile
foreach($row in $csv) { $row.name = $row.name + "-bedoo" }
$csv | Export-Csv ".\eximtest-a.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# Pipeline approach, pipes $infile to next process as read
Import-Csv $infile | `
    foreach($_) { $row.name = $row.name + "-bedoo" } | `
    Export-Csv ".\eximtest-b.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Running the script produces a correct file (nevermind the quoting). But the pipelined command produces a zero (0) length file.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> .\eximtest.ps1

PS C:\src\powershell> Get-ChildItem .\eximtest-*.csv


    Directory: C:\src\powershell


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        2016-08-17     14:12         94 eximtest-a.csv
-a---        2016-08-17     14:12          0 eximtest-b.csv
```

**Many thanks all. Working version.**

```
Import-Csv $infile | `
    Foreach-Object {$_.name = $_.name + "-bedoo"; $_} | `
    Export-Csv ".\eximtest-b.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline version is mixed up and has no output (you modify, but don't write anything to the output pipeline).

```
Import-Csv $infile |
    ForEach-Object {
        # This sets the value
        $_.Name = $_.Name + '-bedoo'
        # This is output (post-modification)
        $_
    } |
    Export-Csv ".\eximtest-b.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

$Row is not defined in your pipeline approach. Change $row to $_ and change the foreach ($_) loop to just foreach and you should be good.

```
# Pipeline approach, pipes $infile to next process as read
Import-Csv $infile | `
    foreach { $_.name = $_.name + "-bedoo" } | `
    Export-Csv ".\eximtest-b.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```